# Is this script at risk of SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

Just asking if you guys can notice any SQL injection possiblities in this code, please reply if found any. This code is to load simple 'jokes' from a MySQL database. Thanks :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        try
        {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=website', 'root', '');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $error = '<font color="red"><strong><p align="center">Unable to connect to the database server. Please visit again later!</p></strong></font>';
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        try
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT joketext FROM joke';
            $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $error = '<font color="red"><strong><p align=center>Error Fetching Jokes</p></strong></font>';
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        while ($row = $result->fetch())
        {
            $jokes[] = $row['joketext'];
        }

        include 'jokes.html.php'; // Array listing parse
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any user input in there. So it can't be.. But well done for using PDO and not mysql_*.

Answer (score 4):

You don't take any user input, so it can't be.

Comment: True in this case. But shouldn't be generalized based on user input. Code can still be susceptible to second order injection without direct input variables. (Reusing results from one query unesacped in another database statement).

Comment: @mario Second order injection comes from user input.

Answer (score 2):

A SQL injection happens when you don't sanitize user input.

Example:

```
"SELECT joketext FROM joke WHERE joker = " . $_GET['joker']
```

This is bad because I can put anything I want in the variable (`http://yoursite.com/joke.php?joker=whatever`) and it will get executed!

Your take no user input so I don't have any opportunity to do such a thing. The query you execute is the same every time and is hard coded in your php file.

Read more about SQL injections on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).